# How to add custom icon to JqGrid top-level toolbar button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jqgrid

I have used the info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3836241/how-do-i-add-a-custom-icon-to-a-standard-jquery-ui-theme) to add a custom button in JqGrid top level toolbar using code below in IE9.

Caret icon appears instead of image. IE9 network tab shows that request for Images/calendar.png is not issued.

```
   $grid.jqGrid('navButtonAdd', '#grid_toppager', {
        caption: '',
        id: "grid_mybutton",

        buttonicon: 'my-image',
        onClickButton: function () { 
            window.location =  'Report';
          }
    });
```

css file:

```
.ui-button .ui-icon.my-image { 
    background-image: url("Images/calendar.png"); 
    width: 16; 
    height: 16;  
} 

.ui-button.ui-state-hover .ui-icon.my-image { 
    background-image: url("Images/calendar.png"); 
    width: 16; 
    height: 16;  
}
```

How to add custom icon ?

Comment: Are you talking about replacing the icon for the x in the top-right corner of the dialog, or do you want to add a new clickable icon to the toolbar with it's own action?

Comment: I want add new button with icon `Images/calendar.png` and custom action `window.location =  'Report'`

Comment: Your css of:

    ".ui-button.ui-state-hover .ui-icon.my-image"

should be 

     ".ui-button, .ui-state-hover, .ui-icon, .my-image"  Update: I added more of an explanation in an answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The jQuery styles will always over-write your styles as they are applied last.

In addition to what `jjay225` pointed out ones you fixed your references, add the `!important` tag to your image style to ensure it is always applied.

Try it out in the below demo, remove the `!important`, and you get the `^`, add it again and you get your image.

See [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/rmN73/1/)

Not having your full code I simply added an icon to the toolbar with jQuery `append()` and added the required CSS.

Using any debugging tool though, i.e: FireBug in FF and the build-in ones in Chrome or IE, you can check the exact class/id values of your new icon and fix any css reference issues you may have.

Comment: That "!important" is very important Andrus. Good addition Francois

Answer (score 1):

Your css of

```
.ui-button.ui-state-hover .ui-icon.my-image
```

should be

```
 .ui-button, .ui-state-hover, .ui-icon, .my-image
```

Why not try just have the class

```
.my-image
{
    background-image: url("Images/calendar.png"); 
     width: 16; 
     height: 16;  
  }
```