# How to customize jquery UI accordion icons?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, icons, accordion, jquery-ui-accordion

I want to customize the icons for the accordion. I found the page here
http://jqueryui.com/accordion/#custom-icons
But it seems to give a name of something there for the header and activeHeader.

How do you do this, if you just have a path to an image file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would need to write some custom CSS to replace the jQuery UI icon that you plan to use. For example, in the case of the example code:

```
ui-icon-circle-arrow-e {background-image:url('path/to/my/images/filename.png') !important;}
```

Very similar to this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3836241/how-do-i-add-a-custom-icon-to-a-standard-jquery-ui-theme)

Answer (score 34):

Here's another option should you need the standard icons for another part of your project:

**[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/5Bz8g/63/)**

JS

```
 $(function () {
     var icons = {
         header: "iconClosed",    // custom icon class
         activeHeader: "iconOpen" // custom icon class
     };
     $("#accordion").accordion({
         icons: icons
     });
 });
```

CSS

```
.ui-icon.iconOpen {
    background:url('YOUR Image HERE') no-repeat;
    background-size:20px;
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
}
.ui-icon.iconClosed {
    background:url('YOUR Image HERE') no-repeat -5px;
    background-size:30px;
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
}
```

Comment: why is the iconClosed background size 30px, and the first one only 20px?

Comment: @sneaky it just looked better with the particular images used.

Comment: @sneaky the size and aspect ratio of the original images used in the example are different.

Comment: doesn't work for me. i can see in conole log the css is loading but not showing in browser.

Comment: @bonez I'm not sure what you mean. Can you share a fiddle showing the problem?

Comment: It may be helpful to know that older versions of jQuery UI use `headerSelected` instead of `activeHeader`.

Answer (score -1):

```js
$("#accordion").accordion({
  accordion: true,
  speed: 500,
  closedSign: '<img src="../../images/arrow-forward.png"/>',
  openedSign: '<img src="../../images/arrow-down.png"/>'
});
```